# iTextSharp `save as` to save to a user defined location

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, visual-studio-2012, save-as

I have used a [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MyhLW84cWrY) to learn how to implement a button on my .net c# that converts text to PDF. This works totally fine but it saves to a pre-defined location specified in one of the lines in the code.

```
PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream("J:/Module Results.pdf", FileMode.Create));
```

This saves the PDF to the `J` drive but instead I would like it to give the user a `Save as` option as happens when downloading anything else from any website.

Does anyone know how this can be done? Or if this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

The end user can't directly create and save the `pdf` file. What you need is to create a file and save it to server side. 

And then provide the path of the file in a link to download that file.